# What is the meaning of symbols $\delta f$ and $\delta^2f$?

Tags: soft-question, notation, differentiation, continuum-mechanics, variational-calculus

Professor was using these symbols to derive the continuity equation. He defined the infinitesimal mass as $\delta^2m=\rho \delta V$ and the mass that leaves some closed boundary $\partial V$ as $\delta m=\iint\limits_{\partial V} {\delta^2m}$. The symbols look like the symbols for first and second variation, but I cannot intuitively connect that two. To be clear, I understand the derivation and I have seen it before, but in different form.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): It can mean various things. Can you point to a published reference besides what the professor wrote?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. $\delta^2m$ is $\rho  \vec {v}  \delta {t}  d\vec S$ and therefore $\frac{\delta m}{\delta t}$, the rate of change of mass through some surface area $\partial V$ is equal to the surface integral of mass flux $\rho \vec v$ over that surface.